# Ternary Operator shows 1 instead on null

Tags: php

Hello I am using ternary operator to show links in case if they exist, in case if the database field is NULL I don't want to show anything. Right now it is showing `1`.  how I can escape this ?

```
echo "".(($row['photo_01']=='')? :'<li><img src="uploads/'.$row['photo_01'].'"></li>')."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you leave the second part of the ternary operator empty, it is equivalent to this:

```
echo "".(($row['photo_01']=='')
    ? ($row['photo_01']=='') // this is duplicated
    :'<li><img src="uploads/'.$row['photo_01'].'"></li>')."
```

More generalized:

```
($x ? $x : $y) === ($x ?: $y)
```

`($row['photo_01']=='')` is evaluated to be `true`, which is echoed out as `1`, so you need to update your code to be like this:

```
echo "".(($row['photo_01']=='')? '' :'<li><img src="uploads/'.$row['photo_01'].'"></li>')."
```

Of course you could always clean it up like this:

```
echo "".($row['photo_01'] ? '<li><img src="uploads/'.$row['photo_01'].'"></li>' : '')."
```

Answer (score 1):

Use empty quotes to represent null ' ', as well as put the result of the ternary in a variable then use it in the echo to prevent cofusion:

```
$result = ($row['photo_01']=='') ? '' :'<li><img src="uploads/'.$row['photo_01'].'"></li>';

echo  $result;
```